# osm2pgsql cannot connect to postgis database, running on a Bitnami project installer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, osm2pgsql

Based on [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYlkb4hba3o) I am trying to import an `.osm.pbf` file into my `PostGIS` database, which is running on my `Postgres` Bitnami installation here:

```
[bitnami@ip-xxx]/usr/share/proj$ which postgres 
/opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin/postgres
```

but I am getting an error, where `osm2pgsql` seems unable to connect to my database:

```
[bitnami@xxx]/home/.../geoserver_data/OSM$ osm2pgsql -E 900913 -d geodb -U geouser -W -S /usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style washington-latest.osm.pbf
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.82.0 (64bit id space)

Password:
Error: Connection to database failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Yet, my `Postgres` install is listening to port `5432` under `/opt/bitnami/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` as follows:

```
[bitnami@ip-xxx]/home/.../postgresql/share$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13969/postgres  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1876491  13969/postgres      /opt/bitnami/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

It seems that `osm2pgsql` is having trouble finding my database. I know that I have my postgres server running, as shown here:

```
[bitnami@ip-xxx]/usr/share/proj$ ps aux | grep postgres
postgres   982  0.0  0.0 247712   468 ?        S    Oct21   0:17 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
postgres   986  0.0  0.6 247856  7028 ?        Ss   Oct21   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
postgres   987  0.0  0.0 247712   140 ?        Ss   Oct21   0:14 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
postgres   988  0.0  0.0 247712   104 ?        Ss   Oct21   0:12 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
postgres   989  0.0  0.1 248568  1088 ?        Ss   Oct21   0:12 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
postgres   990  0.0  0.0 103520   536 ?        Ss   Oct21   0:22 postgres: stats collector process                                                                                           
postgres 11111  0.0  1.1 171996 11876 ?        S    04:28   0:00 /opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /opt/bitnami/postgresql/data
postgres 11113  0.0  0.0 171996   876 ?        Ss   04:28   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                      
postgres 11114  0.0  0.1 171996  1696 ?        Ss   04:28   0:00 postgres: writer process                                            
postgres 11115  0.0  0.0 171996   932 ?        Ss   04:28   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                                        
postgres 11116  0.0  0.2 172844  2084 ?        Ss   04:28   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                               
postgres 11117  0.0  0.1  27812  1120 ?        Ss   04:28   0:00 postgres: stats collector process                                   
bitnami  13358  0.0  0.0  11752   924 pts/6    S+   09:10   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
root     26079  0.0  0.0  64536    32 pts/7    S    Nov26   0:00 su postgres
postgres 26080  0.0  0.0  21100   200 pts/7    S    Nov26   0:00 bash
```

I also have the following under my `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`, `/opt/bitnami/postgres/share/pg_hba.conf` and my `/opt/bitnami/postgres/data/pg_hba.conf`, which seems like is should allow access for my `geouser`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   geodb           geouser                                 md5
```

Any suggestions about how I can import my OSM data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I created a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /opt/bitnami/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

It is working fine. It seems that `osm2pgsql` only looks for the socket at `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`. My question is related to this one here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432